# Python and XML Processing

Tags: python, xml

I have used urllib to get the following data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<videos xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
        xmlns:www="http://www.www.com"">
  <video type="cl">
    <cd>
      <src lang="music">http://www.google.com/ </src>
    </cd>
  </video>
</videos>
```

I want to get `http://www.google.com/` out, here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><videos xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:www="http://www.www.com""><video type="cl"><cd><src lang="music">http://www.google.com/ </src></cd></video></videos>'
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
geturl=tree.findtext('/video/cd/src').strip()
print geturl
```

I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

Obviously, the `findtext` failed. I tried `findtext('src')`, also wont work.

Whats wrong?

Comment: What's the traceback for the error? Also, running this code does not produce the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the first forward-slash from the path: `video/cd/src`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
data='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><videos xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:www="http://www.www.com"><video type="cl"><cd><src lang="music">http://www.google.com/ </src></cd></video></videos>'''
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
geturl=tree.findtext('video/cd/src').strip()
print geturl
```

yields

```
http://www.google.com/
```

The forward-slash indicates an absolute path, which is not allowed on elements.

PS. There is also a syntax error in the data you posted: `xmlns:www="http://www.www.com""` has two double-quotes at the end...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didnt use the first forward-slash in my code. It is just a typo here. I solved my problem with Beautifulsoup. The most possible reason is informal xml that ElementTree cant deal with.